# API for accessing UI elements in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, accessibility

We are developing an application which helps people with reading disabilities. The user can let the application read out loud any text on the screen (menus, button labels, window titles, etc.) by hovering the mouse cursor over it (I know many OS’s can do this already, but this is a pedagogical tool and we are doing some additional stuff). We have a working application for Windows and now we would like to do something similar in OS X. Basically we want to implement something similar to the VoiceOver feature of OS X. My question is if there is an API we can use to access UI elements in OS X (like the Microsoft Active Accessibility for Windows). I have been reading about the Mac OS X Accessibility, but that seems more like an API to enable accessibility in your own app, not to access elements from the OS (or other apps). Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accessibility will allow you to access other apps' UI elements as well. Check out the [UIElementInspector sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) on Apple's site. It is very close to what you want to do.

Comment: Thanx, this is exactly what I was after. But if I understand this correctly I can only use this API to extract data from Cocoa (and Carbon) applications because the information is provided by the framework, not the OS it self. Does it mean that I cannot get any info from applications which have nothing to do with Cocoa (for instance Java applications)?

Comment: @NobleK: I honestly don't know. I don't interact with a lot of GUI Java apps on a daily basis. I suspect it might work since Apple created its own customized JVM fork mainly to make it integrate into the OS better. At any rate, the system GUI frameworks are pretty close to *being* the OS. Java is the only major kind of app I can think of that *might* not go through Cocoa. All the cross-platform windowing toolkits out there go through Cocoa or Carbon on the Mac. There's not really a practical lower-level way to make a graphical application.

Comment: On Windows Swing Applications basically appear to be black boxes you can not inspect the components using the UIAutomation API of Windows which is the updated version of Accessibility API for Windows. If you have any information about swing application and the accessibility API I would love to hear it.

As a fall back using SWT and JFace is usually using native controls and therefore is visual to Accessibility APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called the Accessibility API. It's very well documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/

Comment: Your first link is now 404.

Comment: Fixed the old link. It looks like 10.10 introduced a new API so the docs have changed.